# Should idempotent POST API call check API request payload before using client token to check idempotency?

Tags: api, rest, idempotent

I'm building a idempotent REST based POST API call. I want to implement idempotency behavior to avoid clients creating duplicate resource during network failure & timeout. Client passes a ClientToken in request header of every API call. My POST request has standard payload and I have validation logic around it. What is ideal idempotency behavior expected from an API during a retry? Should it depend just on the ClientToken and ignore request payload or should I run the validation logic on the request payload before invoking idempotent checks using ClientToken?

Answer (score 1):

It depends, but for the idempotent API's that I've implemented, I always check the token first.

Because I only store the idempotency token in the same transaction as the changes made to the database (inserting the new resource for example) I know that if it is their, whatever is being requested has already been committed and worked previously.

If the token exists, I'll return a 201 created to the client with the link (for a POST) immediately before validating the payload.

The reason for this is that the rules of the game for clients is the idempotency token allows you to retry EXACTLY the same request. If someone writes a client that is silly enough to change the payload and use the same idempotency token, that's on their head.

The bonus of checking the idempotency token first is it can potentially save a bit of validation work, if the validation of a payload is heavy going.

Answer (score -1):

First of all, POST, as a HTTP method, is not idempotent. Idempotent means that multiple identical requests should have the same effect as a single request.

If you change the payload, you no longer have identical requests. If you use them with the same token then what happens on the server? Does a second, different request, cause side effects? If it does then it is no longer indempotent. If on the other hand the result is the same then the method is indempotent so the payload does not matter but you no longer have identical requests needed to respect idempotency of HTTP.

I would personally check the request to have the same payload and reject subsequent requests that have a different payload.

Comment: Got it. Should we return different error in cases where clients had messed up the request - same ClientToken but different payload? Server can't process it as new request as it sees same ClientToken and it can't return previous successful response as request payload is not identical.

Comment: @user3236022: yes, you could return a status code in the 4xx range for extra requests with the same client token but different payload

Comment: The HTTP standards only say that POST is treated as not safe in terms of all the intermediates such as proxies etc... It is entirely possible, and indeed good practice, to implement idempotent POSTs using a token. However, your clients need to play by the rules and only retry a failed request with the same payload. If they don't, then the results are on their head.

Comment: you should return the same code you would as if it was the first request, since the client is retrying and obviously hasn't received the first response. One of the advantages of idempotency is it allows client retry/failure logic to be simplified. If your going to slap them with a 4xx on their retry, since they obviously didn't get the first response, now they have to go and GET resources to figure out what happened !